# Is theme _stata still available in ggplot2 for R? I get an error message

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use `theme_stata` for my ggplot. Using the following code, everything works, except for the theme:

```r
df3 <- data_summary(panel_data, 
                    varname = "invest_amnt", 
                    groupnames = c("trend_id", "path_id")
)

df3$path_id <- as.factor(df3$path_id)
df3$trend_id <- as.factor(df3$trend_id)

head(df3)
  
df.mean <- df3 %>% 
  group_by(path_id) %>% 
  mutate(ymean = mean(invest_amnt))
     
p <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = path_id, y = invest_amnt, fill = trend_id)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = invest_amnt-sd, ymax = invest_amnt+sd), 
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
      
p + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  theme_stata() + 
  scale_color_stata()
    
p + 
  labs(title = "", x = "path)", y = "Invested Amount") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#f55b5b','#23036b','#e3d613' )) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_errorbar(data = df.mean, aes(x = path_id , ymax = ymean, ymin = ymean),
                size=1.5, linetype = "longdash", inherit.aes = F, width = 1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in theme_stata() : could not find function "theme_stata"
```

Comment: `theme_stata()` is part of the `ggthemes` package, not `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2):

`theme_stata()` is a part of `ggthemes` [package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggthemes/versions/3.5.0/topics/theme_stata). The package should be loaded with `library(ggthemes)`.